# SQL records with common ID - update all with single user defined function call

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery, user-defined-functions

ClientInfo Table

```
------------------------------------------------------------
||ClientInfoID |    ClientID  | FName   |  MName |  LName ||
||1            |      1       |  Don    |  A     |   Smith||
||2            |      1       |  Dan    |  A     |   Smith||
||3            |      1       |  Dan    |  G     |   Smith||
||4            |      2       |  John   |  D     |   Doe  ||
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Trying to get an sql call right in SQL Server.  I've written a user defined function that generates a random first/middle/last names which is working fine.  My challenge is that I want ALL records with the same ClientID to get updated with the result of a single call to my rename function (actually 3 calls = 1 for first, middle, and last name).

My attempt below is chaning EVERY record in ClientInfo DIFFERENT names instead of giving all ClientID = 1 records the SAME f/m/last names, ClientID = 2 the SAME f/m/last names, etc.

DESIRED RESULT:

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    ||ClientInfoID | ClientID  |    FName   | MName | LName   ||
    ||1            |   1       |     Bill   | X     | Brown   ||
    ||2            |   1       |     Bill   | X     | Brown   ||
    ||3            |   1       |     Bill   | X     | Brown   ||
    ||4            |   2       |     Kate   | Q     | Ramirez ||
    ------------------------------------------------------------
```

ACTUAL RESULT:

```
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    || ClientInfoID |ClientID   |   FName   | MName  |   LName    ||
    || 1            |  1        |     Bill  | X      |   Brown    ||
    || 2            |  1        |     Sue   | R      |   Henderson||
    || 3            |  1        |     Phil  | S      |   Anders   ||
    || 4            |  2        |     Kate  | Q      |   Ramirez  ||
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

My SQL call

```
UPDATE ClientInfo
SET FirstName = X.NewFirstName
    ,MiddleName = X.NewMiddleName
    ,LastName = X.NewLastName
FROM (
    SELECT UniqueClientID
        ,LastClientInfoID
        ,NewFirstName
        ,NewMiddleName
        ,NewLastName
    FROM (
        (
            SELECT ClientID AS UniqueClientID
                ,MAX(ClientInfoID) AS LastClientInfoID
            FROM ClientInfo
            GROUP BY ClientID
            ) A INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ClientInfoID
                ,NewFirstName = dbo.fnSampleFnameMnameLname(0, @MaxName, '')
                ,NewMiddleName = dbo.fnSampleFnameMnameLname(1, @MaxName, MiddleName)
                ,NewLastName = dbo.fnSampleFnameMnameLname(2, @MaxName, '')
            FROM ClientInfo
            ) B ON A.LastClientInfoID = B.ClientInfoID
        )
    ) X
WHERE ClientID = X.UniqueClientID
```

Comment: Is there a table that ClientID is the primary key of?

Comment: Is it a typo that your Dan is called Don?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.  Moved the creation of names attached to each clientid into a temp table first.  Then just joined on clientinfo on that temp table to pull in the new sample names.

```
SELECT  ClientID, NewFirstName, NewMiddleName, NewLastName
INTO    #TempSampleNames
FROM    ( 
        (
            SELECT  ClientID,
            MAX(ClientInfoID) MaxClientInfoID
            FROM    ClientInfo
            GROUP BY    ClientID
        ) A
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  ClientInfoID
            ,NewFirstName =     dbo.fnSampleFnameMnameLname(0, @MaxName, '')
            ,NewMiddleName =    dbo.fnSampleFnameMnameLname(1, @MaxName, MiddleName)
            ,NewLastName =  dbo.fnSampleFnameMnameLname(2, @MaxName, '')    
            FROM    ClientInfo 
        ) B ON A.MaxClientInfoID = B.ClientInfoID
    )


UPDATE  ClientInfo
SET 
FirstName =     B.NewFirstName
,MiddleName =   B.NewMiddleName
,LastName =     B.NewLastName
FROM ClientInfo A
INNER JOIN #TempSampleNames B ON A.ClientID = B.ClientID



DROP TABLE #TempSampleNames
```

Comment: Congrats! Just one hint: You should rather use a table valued variable then a #table: DECLARE @TempSampleNames TABLE(col1,col2,...) Btw: If you have a look to my example you can achieve this with some lines less :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a `Client` table, and ClientID is a primary or unique key in that table, and ClientInfo has a one-to-many relationship with it on ClientID, then you could simply do this:

```
UPDATE  A
SET 
FirstName =                 B.NewFirstName
,MiddleName =               B.NewMiddleName
,LastName =                 B.NewLastName
FROM ClientInfo A
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  ClientID
                ,NewFirstName =             dbo.fnSampleFnameMnameLname(0, @MaxName, '')
                ,NewMiddleName =            dbo.fnSampleFnameMnameLname(1, @MaxName, MiddleName)
                ,NewLastName =              dbo.fnSampleFnameMnameLname(2, @MaxName, '')    
        FROM    Client 
    ) B ON A.ClientID = B.ClientID
```

Comment: Still getting different names for every record - so records with same clientid are getting different names.

Also the inner select is referrencing MiddleName from ClientInfo table but this select is now on Client table (MUST admit I really like your idea to inner join on the Client table -- a fresh way for me to see this - thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

I would change the function from scalar to table valued

That's just a proof of concept. I fill the existing FirstName into the function to proof that it's always the same with one client...
ATTENTION: I used your data as given in your question. One 'Don' should rather be a 'Dan' I assume...

EDIT: expand example...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSampleFNameMnameLname
(
    @Inp VARCHAR(30) --don't quite understand the @Maxname...
) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS
--Create your Names in one go (this is inline syntax, maybe you'd do it with multi statement syntax...)
RETURN SELECT @Inp+'FName1' AS FName,@Inp+'MName1' AS MName,@Inp+'LName1' AS LName;
GO

DECLARE @ClientInfo TABLE(ClientInfoID INT,ClientID INT, FName VARCHAR(30),MName  VARCHAR(30),LName VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @ClientInfo VALUES
    (1,1,'Don','A','Smith')
   ,(1,1,'Dan','A','Smith')
   ,(1,1,'Dan','A','Smith')
   ,(1,1,'John','D','Doe');
SELECT * FROM @ClientInfo AS ci
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSampleFNameMnameLname(ci.FName) AS NewNames
```

Comment: @Maxname is the # of entries in the name table.  I calculate it once and use it multiple times in a number of function calls.  

Function was scalar because I often only pull 1 name.  But I can see advantage of returning mult names in table. Thanks for the input!

Comment: One good thing to know is, that with inline-table-valued-function the optimizer is able to do only what is needed to be done. So: When you call such a function with SELECT FName FROM dbo.fnXXX it will just skip anything you do to construct output for MName and LName. Btw: If you "calculate something once for multiple use" you should think of a CTE.

Comment: Fantastic Shnugo.  Appreciate you taking the time to share!

Comment: Glad to help! Please vote up and/or mark the answer if helpfull

Comment: @Dan Spurgin: Just added a new example